# format ext4 options for cloud-init?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-init

I want to specified some mkfs.ext4 options like reserved-blocks-percentage=0 in the cloud-init config file but don't find a possibility.
Someone has already try it ?

Here the part of file, this is a filesystem direct on disk (vmware) :

```
    # disk 2
    - type: disk
      id: opt-disk
      ptable: gpt
      path: /dev/sdb
      preserve: false
    - id: opt-format
      type: format
      fstype: ext4
      volume: opt-disk
    - id: opt-mount
      type: mount
      path: /opt
      device: opt-format
```

There exists a property like `fsoptions: xxx` of something ?
Thanks

Comment: Try askubuntu.com. SO is only for programming questions.

Comment: cloud-init is programming for system, I'll see some posts with this tag, but ok I'll try

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for creating filesystems on cloud-init is [here](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#disk-setup), see the `fs_setup` key.

However, your example keys don't like `cloud-init` keys.

Are you sure you're talking about cloud-init specifically? Or maybe you're asking about [something](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference) [else](https://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/storage.html)?